# How to Fix 405 Not Allowed in (Curl PHP)

Tags: php, curl

I tried curl login, but the result is always go to *405 Not Allowed*. How can fix it?

i think this SSL problem so i install HTTPS to my localhost but it doesnt change the results remain 405 Not Allowed :'(

```
$ch = curl_init();
$data=array(
'email'=>'user@admin.com',
'password'=>'password',
);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://2secure.jenius.co.id/#/authentication/login");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($data));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, 'cookie-name.txt');  
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, 'cookie-name.txt');
$hasil=curl_exec($ch);

curl_close ($ch);
echo $hasil;
```

Comment: 405 means *method* not allowed, which means you're doing a POST but it expects a GET. (Or a PUT, or whatever...)

Comment: Also you can't have a `#` fragment in a URL, those are client-side _only_.